# Can't get the plaintext without using foreach

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to use `simple_html_dom` to get the plaintext ('THIS TEXT') of one HTML element:

```
<div class="parent">
    <span><i class="fa fa-awesome"></i>THIS TEXT</span>
</div>
```

I'm getting that text by using:

```
foreach($html->find('div.parent span.child') as $text){
    echo $text->plaintext;
}
```

But it is just one element and I'm searching for a way to get that plaintext without using `foreach` loop (since it is just one element).

P.S: I've been trying this:

```
$html->find('div.parent span.child', 1);
```

But `var_dump`-ing that results in a `NULL`.
I also tried this:

```
$html->find('div.delivery-status span.status', 1)->plaintext;
```

But `var_dump`-ing it results in:

> Notice: Trying to get property 'plaintext' of non-object in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\curl\index.php on line 19

I also read the documentation but i can't seem to be able to figure this one out :(. Can somebody please help me or at least point me into the right direction? :-s

Thank you!:D

Comment: Your class names are inconsistent across your question. Are you sure you have the right ones in your actual code?

Comment: There's no `child` class on your span. Use `find('.parent span')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a pretty ancient library, but it looks like a `foreach` loop is how the author intended it to work. This is typical for DOM functions that return a node list for most functions. What's wrong with the loop? You could do this in plain old PHP as well:

```
$html = <<< HTML
<div class="parent">
    <span><i class="fa fa-awesome"></i>THIS TEXT</span>
</div>
HTML;
$dom = new \DomDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new \DOMXPath($dom);
$data = $xpath->query("//div[@class='parent']/span/text()");
echo $data[0]->textContent;
```

Comment: 'ancient library' oky that was funny :D, using this method i'm getting a warning: `Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag header invalid in Entity` :( what should i do?:-s

Comment: See my edit to suppress the warning when loading a full HTML file.

Comment: They're warnings, not errors. HTML parsing is always a tricky business because it's often invalid markup. This method just prevents errors from being output. They can still be caught manually using `libxml_get_errors()`

Comment: oky then i'm going to use it :D, thank you for taking time to help me !:D

Answer (score 1):

The `<span>` in the question does not have a `child` css class, so your selector is not correct. Also you seem to be missing the point that when calling find, the index of children is zero based. Try this:

```
$str = '<div class="parent"><span><i class="fa fa-awesome"></i>THIS TEXT</span></div>';
$html = str_get_html($str);

// no .child for the span, and 0 as the index of target child
print $html->find('div.parent span', 0)->plaintext;
```